# How to hide functions from the autofill menu in Minecraft Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm creating several functions in a behavior pack for Minecraft Bedrock Edition, and I'd like to be able to hide some of them from the autofill/autocomplete menu that lists functions when you first type `/function`. I know that having any incorrect syntax will just invalidate the .mcfunction file completely and remove it from the list, but I'd like the functions to still be usable, just not visible as part of the list.

[image: The function autocomplete menu]

^^This is the menu I'm talking about. I'd like some of them to be visible in this menu, others not visible, but all of them still functional. I'm not sure if there's a way to accomplish this, but I feel like there should be..... Please let me know if there is!



This is the only page I could find that describes the same problem, but they were asking about Java Edition, and I couldn't find a clear answer that worked anyway:

[Prevent functions from showing in autofill command window](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334652/prevent-functions-from-showing-in-autofill-command-window/383483#383483)

Answer (score 2):

What I normally do is put all my hidden functions in a folder (I called mine `back`) so then the function becomes

```
/function back/myfunction
```

Then just tell the person not to run those or something.

What you are asking for I do not believe is directly possible.

Comment: Are they still visible in the autofill menu? And does the specific name of the folder not matter, or does it have to be "back"?

Comment: @Mark they are still visible, yes. What you are trying to do I do not think is possible so I'm just suggesting to have a random folder with any name and tell people not to run functions from there

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out. I figured this out using this page, but there was a missing piece of info I had to find.
[Prevent functions from showing in autofill command window](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334652/prevent-functions-from-showing-in-autofill-command-window/383483#383483)

To hide a function in a behavior pack, the .mcfunction file must contain at least 1 comment in it that starts with `//` instead of the usual `#`, BUT the `min_engine_version` value in the manifest.json file of the behavior pack must be less than `[ 1, 16, 0 ]`. The function will no longer appear in the autofill menu, but it will still work normally when called (assuming there are no other errors with it).

I have no idea why this works, but it does. This might be a thing that gets patched out later.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, it is as simple as just putting HIDE in uppercase before the rest of your function! Here is an exapmple of a setup command I used in one of my addons!

`HIDE`

`scoreboard objectives add grounded dummy`

`scoreboard objectives add cooldown dummy`

`scoreboard objectives add cooldown1 dummy`

`scoreboard objectives add charged_attack dummy`

`scoreboard objectives add choose_temp dummy`

`tag @s add setup`

Trust me, this works! I have been developing packs for a while, and I believe this was added in 1.14.0, so it should work!